# Visual Studio environment alternative

Tags: c++, visual-c++, development-environment, visual-assist

I use Visual C++ (7.1 and 8.0) on huge C++ project. The solution contains thousands of files. Visual Assist helps in jumping to function and class definitions. The problem is that it sometimes becomes too slow. I just can't edit a single letter without delay.

Is there some alternative to this environment? I mean something that may read .sln and .vcproj files, use MSVC debugger, compile with MSVC compiler or even use IncrediBuild if necessary. I don't need any sophisticated features. It should be possible to find and open a file by name and jump to function/class definition from place where it is used.

May be Vim with some plugins? Or something else?

Comment: If you just want to have something else for quick changes in some file, what's wrong with opening the file in notepad really quick to make the change?

Comment: Ugh.  Do you *really* need *all* of the source code?  Modules, stuff you know (and can trust) that works.  Verified by unit tests, nobody should ever muck with them because the build will take 2000 sword strikes.  Yes, pretty tough if you don't have that.  Your IDE agrees.

Comment: @Shynthriir There are a lot of files and I don't remember their exact names and paths. That's why Shift-Alt-O feature from Visual Assist just rocks: http://www.wholetomato.com/products/features/fis.asp . Also, I need an instrument to quicky jump to a function or class definition. Again, I don't remember where some functions and classes are defined.

Comment: Have you tried disabling default intellisense (for example, by renaming feacp.dll)?

Comment: You ask too much. Try writng you code on *NIX systems, and all your slowness would disappear. VIM is far behind VC++ in terms of your demands.

Comment: I guess you just need more SSD and RAM, in that order. Perhaps a faster machine, too, but really, SSD will make all the difference, and RAM will make things better once you have an SSD. And of course you should be running a 64 bit version of Windows.

Comment: There's no such thing as "MSVC debugger" standing alone. It doesn't exist outside of the IDE, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is no alternative to MS Visual studio. I've added separate HDD for source files and it works much better.

Answer (score 0):

Currently i left Visual studio because c++ support just sucks (still using Visual studio 2013 but only for C# projects) 
i use NetBeans right now, and really enjoy the refactoring part.
The visual C++ compiler support can be added using a free plugin ([VCC4N - Visual C++ Compiler For NetBeans](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/42519/?show=true))

good luck

Comment: Which Netbeans Version, 8, 7.4, 7.3 ?